# error - subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Tags: c

I'm having a problem in reversing a string using a function. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int str_length(char lang);

int main()
{
    char language[100];

    int string_length;

    while(1==scanf("%[^\n]", language))
    {
        string_length=str_length(language);
    }

    int i;

    for(i=string_length; i>=0; i--)
    {
        printf("%c\n", language[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

int str_length(char lang)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; lang[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        i++;
    }

    return i;
}
```

The error which is same as the title shows in the line 'for(i=0; lang[i]!='\0'; i++)'.

Please help me to understand the problem.

Comment: `language` is declared as an array of characters, but the prototype/signature for `str_length()` says it is expecting a single char.  Perhaps you meant: `str_length( char * lang );`  <-- note the addition of the `*`

Comment: the function `str_length()` has the variable `i` being incremented by the `for()` statement AND with the body of the `for()` loop, so the returned value will be (approx) twice the actual length of the string.  suggest writing: `for( i=0; lang[i]; i++ );`   Note that the second parameter is simply true (non zero) or false (0) which is all that is needed

Comment: regarding: `while(1==scanf("%[^\n]", language))`  when using `%[^\n]`  always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier (that is one less than the length of the input buffer) to assure that the input buffer is not overrun.  Such overrun results in undefined behavior and can/ will lead to a seg fault event.  Suggest: `while(1==scanf("%99[^\n]", language))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `str_length()` is expecting an `char` as argument but you are passing it a `char *` (a pointer which points at a string) in the call. so, you must use pointer notation or array in your function argument. Like

```
int str_length(char lang[])
{
   //code
}
```

or

```
int str_length(char *lang)
{
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the function definition as

```
int str_length(char lang)
...
```

to

```
int str_length(char *lang)
```

The problem is `lang` is `char` variable so it cannot be accessed like `lang[i]`. You intend to have it as array or pointer.